# Why is my (initial) variable updated when using a recursive function?

Tags: sorting, go, recursion, quicksort

I decided to create the quick sort algorithm in go.

My code for the quick sort is:

```golang
package sorting

func QuickSort(input []int) []int {

    if len(input) <= 1 {
        return input
    }

    sorted := input
    pivotIndx := len(sorted) - 1 // The index of the last item of the array
    pivot := sorted[pivotIndx]   // The value of the last item in the array
    curLowIndx := 0

    for indx, val := range sorted {
        if val < pivot {
            // Swap the items
            sorted[indx], sorted[curLowIndx] = sorted[curLowIndx], sorted[indx]
            // Increment the index on which the low position is stored.
            // We need to do this so that the next item that is lower can be stored/swapped with the correct position
            curLowIndx = curLowIndx + 1
        }
    }

    sorted[curLowIndx], sorted[pivotIndx] = sorted[pivotIndx], sorted[curLowIndx]

    // Sort the sub-arrays
    QuickSort(sorted[:curLowIndx])
    QuickSort(sorted[curLowIndx+1:])

    return sorted

}
```

Code for the main file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/.../.../sorting"
)

func main() {

    // Sorting examples
    toSort := []int{100, 20, 70, 30, 90, 40, 120, 123, 10, 23}

    fmt.Println(toSort) // returns: [100 20 70 30 90 40 120 123 10 23]
    shouldBeSorted := sorting.QuickSort(toSort) 
    fmt.Println(shouldBeSorted) // returns: [10 20 23 30 40 70 90 100 120 123]
    fmt.Println(toSort) // ALSO returns: [10 20 23 30 40 70 90 100 120 123]

}
```

In my main function I have a slice in a variable which I want to be sorted (`toSort`).
I create a new variable in which I want to store the sorted slice (`shouldBeSorted`).
But here I find something that I did not expect, nor understand. 
When I call the `sorting.QuickSort(toSort)` it sorts it and also assigns the return value to the `shouldBeSorted` variable, but next to that it also updates the `toSort` variable with the result from `sorting.QuickSort(toSort)`.

I have read about the usage of pointers in go and would expect this behavior when passing a pointer through, but not when passing a 'regular' variable.

So my actual question is: why does this happen? Why does it change the `toSort` variable? Is there something I did wrong or is this expected and why would this be expected?

Side note:
The same thing happens in the QuickSort function it self when the recursion happens:

```golang
QuickSort(sorted[:curLowIndx])
QuickSort(sorted[curLowIndx+1:])
```

I first though that I would need to combine the slices I would get back, but apparently it updates the original sorted slice.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 4):

Slices in go actually consist of a struct with meta info and a pointer to a contiguous memory location that stores the actual data. Even though you're passing `toSort` by value, the copied meta struct still refers to the same underlying memory location. That is why `toSort` gets changed as well.

If you do not want this to happen, you can use copy to create a new slice and pass it on.

Slice Internals: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Copy: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy

Answer (score 3):

Slices are just pointers to the underlying data so when you update the given parameter, you are changing the actual data. That's why you need to copy your data:

```
func copySlice(s []int) []int {
    c := make([]int, len(s))
    copy(c, s)
    return c
}

func main() {
    toSort := []int{100, 20, 70, 30, 90, 40, 120, 123, 10, 23}
    sorted := sorting.QuickSort(copySlice(toSort))
    fmt.Println(toSort)
    fmt.Println(sorted)
}
```